# Want to filter through an array which is structured like a JSON (Angular typescript)

Tags: arrays, json, angular, typescript, filter

I have a string array where records look like

```
0: {Name: 'AFGHANISTAN', ShortName: 'AFG'}
1: {Name: 'ALAND ISLANDS', ShortName: 'ALD'}
2: {Name: 'ALBANIA', ShortName: 'ALB'}
3: {Name: 'ALGERIA', ShortName: 'DZA'}
4: {Name: 'AMERICAN PACIFIC TERRITORIES', ShortName: 'UMI'}
5: {Name: 'AMERICAN SAMOA', ShortName: 'ASM'}
6: {Name: 'AMERICAN VIRGIN ISLANDS', ShortName: 'VIR'}
7: {Name: 'ANDORRA', ShortName: 'AND'}
8: {Name: 'ANGOLA', ShortName: 'AGO'}
9: {Name: 'ANGUILLA', ShortName: 'AIA'}
10: {Name: 'ANTARCTICA', ShortName: 'ATA'}
11: {Name: 'ANTIGUA & BARBUDA', ShortName: 'ATG'}
```

I want to filter this array so the records only hold the country data, for example;

```
0: {AFGHANISTAN}
1: {'ALAND ISLANDS'}
2: {'ALBANIA'}
3: {'ALGERIA'}
4: {'AMERICAN PACIFIC TERRITORIES'}
5: {'AMERICAN SAMOA'}
6: {'AMERICAN VIRGIN ISLANDS'}
7: {'ANDORRA'}
8: {'ANGOLA'}
9: {'ANGUILLA'}
10: {'ANTARCTICA'}
11: {'ANTIGUA & BARBUDA'}
```

how could I achieve this in Angular and typescript? I've been trying to solve it for ages

I've tried to use the filter method but I don't think it's used for what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: You want to use [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Comment: This has nothing todo with Angular or TypeScript... just saying

Answer (score 3):

You can use the built in array functions and have it only be the Name.

`var newArray = oldArray.map(({ Name }) => Name);`